# Unexpected loop behavior when appending lists

Tags: python, loops

I wanted to know why the below code works as expected. The aim was to make a list of lists, where each inner list contains books from a particular author. A friend accidentally appended into the temporary list right after the temporary list's declaration and the code still worked. I was appending after the inner-for loop, which works like normal.

Code:

```
all_books = []
for author in os.listdir("books/"):
    tmp = []

    all_books.append(tmp)

    for book in os.listdir("books/" + author + "/"):
        tmp.append(book)

print(all_books)
```

Output:

```
[['On_the_Origin_of_Species.txt', 'The_Power_of_Movement_in_Plants.txt'],
 ['Adventures_of_Sherlock_Holmes.txt',
  'Memoirs_of_She rlock_Holmes.txt',
  'The_Lost_World.txt'],
 ['A_Treatise_of_Human_Nature.txt', 'An_Enquiry_Concerning_Human_Understanding.txt'],
 ['Treasure_Island.txt'],
 ['Ivanhoe A_Romance.txt', 'The_Lady_of_the_Lake.txt']]
```

Comment: Please put your code into the question as text - not an image

Comment: In both cases, the list `all_books` has a reference to the `tmp` list, since you've just appended it. Any changes you make to the underlying list via the `tmp` handle will be reflected in all references to that underlying list. It doesn't matter in what order you append `tmp`, or append items to `tmp`, just as long as you do it within one iteration of the primary loop (since `tmp` gets rebound to a new list each iteration.)

Comment: I used an OCR tool to convert your code image to text, and then put it in your post. Please just post the code, and its output, as text in the future.

Comment: See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you assign `tmp` into `all_data`. Instead of creating a **new copy of `tmp`**, it makes a **reference of `tmp` variable**. That's causes this issue.

Identical objects have the same **`id`** in python. If `id` is same then name references to same variable.

```
all_data = []
tmp = []
all_data.append(tmp)
print("all_data_tmp id",id(all_data[0]))
print("tmp id",id(tmp))
tmp.append(2)
print("all_data",all_data)
```

Output:

```
all_data_tmp id 2322674224840
tmp id 2322674224840
all_data [[2]]
```